# Is it possible to execute a function that is written from the javascript of a website with nightmare? Or any other way?

Tags: javascript, nightmare

You know when you visit a page in a website and view the source code, sometimes you see an element execute a javascript function? For example:

```
<button type="button" id="chocolate" onclick="EditShipment()">Click me</button>
```

Can I use nightmare to visit this page and execute EditShipment() ? And if so, is it possible to pass in our own arguments to that function's argument?

Comment: You should do something along the lines of: document.getElementById('#chocolate").onclick = function() { EditShipment('arg'); } and then using .click()

Answer (score 0):

Use the console and type the function name it will execute without clicking the button

Comment: That won't be the same because the `this` value will be different. The `EditShipment` function may depend on `this` being correctly set.